# Boost.Python class inherit from Python type

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have need to expose C++ class but also to inherit from collections.Mapping (to make ** operator available).
Is there way to do that?  Alternative, is there protocol to implement ** for non-mapping types?

Comment: You don't need to inherit from `collections.Mapping`, but you'll probably wish you could. `collections.Mapping` provides a lot of default helper implementations that are a pain to implement manually, especially in C++.

Comment: Appears keys and getitem are sufficient for ** to treat object as mapping, indeed no need to derive from mapping.  still be interesting to know if BP class can inherit from python classes